# Проблема с Opencart, не открывает админку

Tags: php, opencart, openserver, opencart3.x

Я изменил файл по пути C:\ospanel\domains\localhost\system\library\template\twig.php, но у меня выскочила такая ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "return" in C:\OSPanel\domains\storage\modification\system\library\template\twig.php on line 40

Не заходит ни в админку, ни на сайт

Я вернул всё назад как было, но ошибка не исчезла. Не помог ни перезапуск openserver, ни браузера, ничего не работает. Что делать?